# Open Drawer Layout by right swipe from fragment

Tags: android

I have drawer layout and it's working fine. But i want to open navigation drawer  after right-swipe on the fragment. Can you help me with this.

Here is my listener.

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (distanceX > 0)
                    onSwipeRight();
                else
                    onSwipeLeft();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in fragment

```
public class ChartsFragment extends Fragment {

    public ChartsFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_charts, container, false);
        rootView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext()){
            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                Log.v("SWIPE", "SWIPE");
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

But i dont know how to open Drawer, because it's in another class (MainActivity)

```
 mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(linearLayout);
```

thanks to Pankaj Arora
**Solution:**

```
final DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        rootView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext()){
            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
                Log.v("SWIPE", "SWIPE");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you trying to use something like NavigationDrawer?

Comment: get the id of your drawer layout in  fragment using mDrawerLayout = getactivity().findviewbyid(R.id.your drawer layout id);

and then in onswipe right call
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.Start);

Comment: give a try and let me know.

Comment: try this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html

Comment: @Pankaj Arora, thanks a lot man, i appreciate - it worked)

Comment: @JenyaKirmiza then use your upvotes dude. accept by click on check and upvote to my answer if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get the id of drawer layout in your fragment like.

//global

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout
```

in oncreateview

```
mDrawerLayout = getactivity().findviewbyid(R.id.your drawer layout id);
```

and then in onswipe right call

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.Start);
```